Need advice on printing a poster for a CS conference in USA
I am an international student, first time to present in an in person poster session. Unfortuantely, I didn't manage to print my psoter before my flight. The conference is in Atlanta, GA, USA.
I asked the conference organizers they said they wanted it in 4'x6'.
I have 3 days before the conference. Don't know anybody here in Atlanta. Could you recommend an affordable service?
Online services in the US seem pretty expensive.

Yes. It seems too small. Ask.

Checked again with them, turns out it is in feet not inches: 4'x6'

DDG turns up three printers in Atlanta. There probably are dozens more. Are there specific concerns you have?

They are pretty expensive to print in the US, 110$. I am an international student .. is there something cheap in Atlanta?

@Dark_Witch Is the conference at GA Tech? Often university libraries will print posters for much less than print shops. You could perhaps reach out to one of the local organizers or something.

No it is not at GA tech. I asked, they don't offer such a service

Most poster printing places seem to top out at 3'x4' (36"x48"), so you need to split it in two. But, yes, across multiple vendors something on the order of $100 to $130 seems normal.

@Dark_Witch This is a cost that I would ordinarily expect to be paid by whoever is sending you to the conference to present. Though, if it's your own fault that it will cost more than usual to print, the additional cost may not be reimbursed. $110 sounds quite reasonable for a poster that size.

In my country, it costs 10$ in local currency with same quality if not better. :)

Since you have time, you could go to a local university and ask a grad student if they can have their library print the poster. In return, offer to buy them lunch or something (besides covering the printing fee). Would likely be substantially below $110. Bonus points if it is another conference attendee.

Well, ultimately you've made the choice to print in the US where I wager everything costs more than you are used to.

@BryanKrause Some institutions require that posters should be printed at the institute (possibly after confirming institutional logos are present etc.), so they might not reimburse costs in case this policy is violated.

4' x 6' (48 '' * 72'') is huge. I'm used to conference posters sizes stopping at A0, which google tells me is 33.1''  * 46.8'' . Are maths posters really that big ???

@Marianne013 I think the field is less important than the size of the display boards at the place where the conference is. 4x6' is big but not unusually so in my biology world, but it's also common that most presenters bring a poster smaller than the full board dimensions.

I'd guess that the statement 4'x6' is a maximal size and that people will show up with all sorts of poster sizes. If A0 is more convenient to print, that will be fine as well.

I recommend going with a landscape 4'x3' even on a 4'x6' poster board. It's difficult to scan that much vertical space. If the poster boards are anything like the ones I have seen your audience would have to crouch and bend down to see anything on the lower 2'! (You can inquire with the poster organizers though. And, for example, check the poster boards are 6' high and not 6' wide...)

I was in a similar situation once while in a conference outside the US, so I know how you feel.  (I am from the US and it was my first experience with international travel.)
This doesn't directly answer your question, but this is what I did and would do in that situation:

Ask the conference organizers if they can recommend a service

Ask the concierge of your hotel if they either have a print service on site, or if they can recommend a reasonable one in walking distance.  If anyone will have area knowledge that's enough to save you some money, they will.  But don't get your hopes up.

As a last resort, try Fedex, which is ubiquitous in the United States and usually has professional printing facilities.  Prices will vary depending on factors that are too complicated to discuss here, but I doubt you'll do too much better, and you can look them up online.  Ink is expensive.


